# Set landing page for Newsletter Confirm Subscription action

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, landing-pages

When a customer subscribes to newsletter, he receives an email (`app/locale/en_US/email/newsletter_subscr_confirm.html`) which contains a confirmation link.

```
{{var subscriber.getConfirmationLink()}}
```

Is there a way to set the landing page for this link? So I can display a "Thank you" text in there and some other information?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, not so elegant, but it works.

Create a local version of the following file:
`app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php`

In function `confirmAction()`, comment the following line:

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

and replace it with this one:

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('url-key-of-custom-cms-page');
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
```